# Cordova build IOS with CocoaPods configured

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cocoapods, cordova-plugins

I have created a Cordova project using my mac and I added IOS platform tot he project (`cordova platform add ios`)

On adding plugins, [phonegap-plugin-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-plugin-push-nn) plugin expects to use CocoaPods to manage tthe plugin. After adding the plugin and adding the Platfom, I build the project using the command `cordova build ios`

It looks like it is trying to build the CocoaPods project created when adding the platform and it is getting failed. Below is the error. It should build my Xcode project.

```
Error: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

Can anyone help me to build my IOS project.

My Cordova version is 6.4.0; My IOS version is 10.11.6; My Xcode version is 8.1

Thanks.

Comment: hello, ran into same issue, did you manage to sort it out?